Buttons on Dashboard layout missing
This is how the Dashboard layout should look (view of a System Admin) - Containing 3 buttons to the right.


And on this Dashboard View "Edit" and "Subscribe" buttons are gone.
I have looked through all permission sets for Reports and Dashboards which looks fine for the user who is missing the buttons. All the system permissions are checked, same as for System Admin. The dashboards are editable for the regular user, however you need to click on the dropdown menu on the List View page for Dashboards in order to edit, not inside the actual Dashboard.

Check this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8vK1SAJ
